In MongoDB 'show dbs ' command show mongodbserver[unauthorized ]
enter image description here
i did my installation with help of YouTube tutorial. after that in my cmd i typed mongosh , it shows perfectly as show in the tutorial and then i write 'show dbs' command but this time in the tutorial it show some database names like admin, user. but for me it shows unauthorized
i installed mongodb community server , mongo shell and set environment variables and finally rebooted my pc

Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

The error message is quite obvious. You did not provide username/password when you connected to database.

when logging in，you need to enter password,or the account you are using does not have the neccessary permissions.
